# xml: issue with CDATA

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    <example>
        A new Employer has signed up!<br /><br />Account Name: ###USERNAME###<br />Email: ###EMAIL###<br />Full Name: ###NAME###<br />Company Name: ###COMPANY###<br />Location: ###CITY### ###STATE###, ###ZIP###
    </example>
</note>
```

It works. But I wonder: `<` and `>` is special character in XML, so why it dose not throw an error since I did not put below texts into `<![CDATA[...]]>`section: `A new Employer has signed up!<br /><br />... ###ZIP###`

Comment: a <br> is also a tag, so why should it? You're just getting this: `<example>*textnode*<br /><br />*textnode*</example>`. Your parser probably just understands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well-formed xml and you haven't specified a schema, so `<br />` is simply interpreted as an xml tag.

however there will be a notable difference in the object model after parsing. the children of `example` will consist of text and element nodes being interspersed whereas a cdata section would enforce to have text nodes exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

You can have text and xml elements nested inside another xml element and

```
<br/>
```

is perfectly valid xml element.